# Propositional Logic : Why is ((p $\Rightarrow$ r) $\land$ (q $\Rightarrow$ r)) $\equiv$ ((p $\lor$ q) $\Rightarrow$ r)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I was working my way through some Propositional Logic and had the following doubt :

> **Why is this true :**
>
> ((p $\Rightarrow$ r) $\land$ (q $\Rightarrow$ r)) $\equiv$ ((p $\lor$ q) $\Rightarrow$ r)

***Please provide an intuitive explanation and not one that uses a truth table or logic identities to simplify the expression . I have already done both of them :)***

Comment: If every **p**enny is a **r**emedy and every **q**uarter is a **r**emedy, then eveything that is a **p**enny **or** a **q**uarter is a **r**emedy. The inverse can be stated similary

Comment: Oh, that is nice and succinct, @GregordeCillia

Comment: Your comment should go before the question in this case, I think. It is important for the answerer to know that you're not looking for a strict proof using logical equivalences (like the one I provided). Of course, I should ideally read the entire question first, but you greatly emphasized the question at hand as opposed to your *real question* which was italicized under it. My proof is very clean logically I feel, but I am not sure you are going to get a more intuitive explanation than the one Gregor de Cillia provided.

Comment: Hi , @GregordeCillia , that is a really wonderful way of expressing this . Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $\;((p\implies r) \wedge (q\implies r))\;$, we know if $p$ is true then $r$ is true, and if $q$ is true then $r$ is true.

This means that if either $p$ or $q$ are true then $r$ is true.  (If one is false and the other true, we still know $r$ must be true; only if both are false do we not know what $r$ is.)

Which is $\;(p\vee q) \implies r\;$ so they are equivalent statements.

$$\therefore ((p\implies r) \wedge (q\implies r)) \equiv ((p\vee q) \implies r)$$

---

Alternatively, since $\;x\implies y\;$ is equivalent to $\;\neg x \impliedby \neg y\;$ then we can substitute a *contraposition* for each implication.

Thus $\;((p\implies r) \wedge (q\implies r))\;$ is equivalent to $\;((\neg p\impliedby \neg r) \wedge (\neg q\impliedby \neg r))\;$, and hence we know if $r$ is false then $p$ is false, and if $r$ is false then $q$ is false.

To simplify, this means that if $r$ is false then both $p$ and $q$ are false.

Which is $\;(\neg p\wedge \neg q) \impliedby \neg r\;$, and this is equivalent to: $\;(p\vee q) \implies r\;$.

$$\because ((\neg p\impliedby \neg r) \wedge (\neg q\impliedby \neg r)) \equiv ((\neg p\wedge \neg q) \impliedby \neg r)$$

$$\therefore ((p\implies r) \wedge (q\implies r)) \equiv ((p\vee q) \implies r)$$

---

Gregor de Cillia put this rather more succinctly in the comments.

> If every **p**enny is a **r**emedy and every **q**uarter is a **r**emedy, then everything that is a **p**enny or a **q**uarter is a **r**emedy. The inverse can be stated similary –  Gregor de Cillia

Comment: @pranav That is what is says.  "if $p$ then $r$" and "$r$ whenever $p$" are both equivalent statements for, $p\implies r$.  They mean that the truth of $p$ is sufficient for the truth of $r$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a no nonsense approach that should be quite easy to follow:
\begin{align}
[(p\to r)\land(q\to r)] &\equiv [(\neg p\lor r)\land (\neg q\lor r)]\tag{$p\to q \equiv \neg p \lor q$}\\[0.5em]
                        &\equiv [(\neg p\land \neg q)\lor r] \tag{distributivity}\\[0.5em]
                        &\equiv [(\neg(\neg p\land \neg q)\to r]\tag{$p\to q \equiv \neg p \lor q$}\\[0.5em]
                        &\equiv (p\lor q)\to r\tag{DeMorgan}
\end{align}
Thus, we have that 
$$
[(p\to r)\land(q\to r)]\equiv (p\lor q)\to r,
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by @GregordeCillia in the comments , the intuitive explanation would be something on these lines :

> - **If** every **p**enny is a **r**emedy and every **q**uarter is a **r**emedy $\equiv$ ((p $\Rightarrow$ r) $\land$ (q $\Rightarrow$ r))
> - **then** everything that is a **p**enny or a **q**uarter is a **r**emedy $\equiv$ ((p $\lor$ q) $\Rightarrow$ r)
> - The inverse can be stated similary